# How to broadcast signed transaction with ethers.js?

Tags: infura, ethers.js

I have a server which signs a transaction and sends it the signedTx back to the client. i want to broadcast this tx from the client side, using Infura as a provider.
I couldnt find info on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out. Dont need to get signer from provider.
The tx can be sent by: `provider.sendTransaction(signedTx)`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using ethers.js V6, you can use the [provider.broadcastTransaction](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Provider-broadcastTransaction) function.